# Htaccess - rewrite субдиректории, исключая файлы

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Добрый день

Есть структура директорий:

```
/
  /a
    /assets
  /b
```

Нужно отправлять все запросы с URL domain.com/a в директорию /b (без редиректа), но оставить возможность прямого доступа до любых файлов в /a (domain.com/a/assets/image.png)

Подскажите как реализовать

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite выполняется так - прочитывает построчно все правила. как только встречает правило которое соответствует условию выполняет его. Поэтому перед правилом редиректа всех запросов с а на b поставьте правило для редиректа всех запросов к a/assets.